# Swapping render buffers after resizing window causes problems

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-11

I'm trying to handle window resize message `WM_SIZE`. 
When I receive it:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        int nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
        int nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
        renderer->Resize(nWidth, nHeight);
        return 1;
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I use new height and width parameters to recreate render target viewport and resize the buffers:

```
void Renderer::Resize(int w, int h)
{
    m_devContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);

    m_renderTargetView->Release();

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = m_swapchain->ResizeBuffers(1, w, h, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);

    ID3D11Texture2D* pBuffer;
    hr = m_swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D),
        (void**)&pBuffer);

    hr = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBuffer, NULL,
        &m_renderTargetView);

    pBuffer->Release();

    m_devContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, NULL);

    // Set up the viewport.
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = w;
    vp.Height = h;
    m_devContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);

}
```

Despite that, the first frame rendered after the resize event cause an error:

```
void Renderer::Render() const
{

    m_devContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, m_clearCol);
    HRESULT ret = m_swapchain->Present(0, 0); //triggered exception here, only the first frame after resize
}
```

Visual studio popup error is:

> ApplicationName.exe has triggered an exception

. No other info, nor catchable exceptions. From some research on the web I guess it could be related to some not released resource or heap corruction.

Any hint? What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: I was missing the console output. Here's the message confirming that's an heap corruction problem:

> HEAP: Free Heap block 44aa468 modified at 44aa4e8 after it was freed
>   application.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

The documentation I followed is from this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Handling_Window_Resizing).

Comment: Are you breaking on [first-chance exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx)?  These are often benign.

Comment: @MooseBoys: nope.. It seems I'm messing up the heap somewhere..still didn't figure out where, but it's related to resize the window.

Comment: Shot in the dark: check `pBuffer`'s reference counts (print the result of your `Release()` call)? If that is the problem, I don't know why; someoen who knows **anything at all** about DirectX will need to answer.

Comment: did u check hr after `m_swapchain->ResizeBuffer()` call? is it `S_OK`?

Comment: also after each `hr = somefunction()`  put code `if(FAILED(hr)){return 1;}` it is wrong way to go in directx not to check return values of directx functions, code can fail anywhere and u won't know where

Comment: @Sly_TheKing: yes, resize buffer is S_OK. I'm not actually checking error explicitly but stepping through the debugger, and all dxcall seems to return S_OK.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Jason Tyler: Yes and no. I mean, I didn't receive any answer on this and after upgrading something (not sure if the driver of visual studio), the bug doesn't show anymore. I didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

don't return 1, use this `return DefWindowProc(blah..)` in your WM_SIZE message. After you've done your resize instructions, windows needs to handle it itself

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement the Resizing code in **WindowProc()**

instead of this, implement it in the Rendering code :

```
void Renderer::Render() const
{
    if (Resizingoccur) // In WindowProc() When the Resizing happen change the value of Resizingoccur to be true
        {
            Resize(nWidth, nHeight);
            Resizingoccur = false;
        }

    m_devContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, m_clearCol);
    HRESULT ret = m_swapchain->Present(0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: Is the Rendering code working in the same thread as WindowProc()?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same error but your code still work in my side, so just try to nullify the render target pointer after releasing it m_renderTargetView= NULL;